# Show notification badge when receiver receive new last message using Laravel 8

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have developed private chat app using laravel and livewire but I want to show notification badge icon when receiver receive new last message notification should be shown when
receiver click to name then it should be hide please help me how can I do that thank ?

[chat app design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfF6n.png)

**Html view**

```
@if(count($users) > 0)
  @foreach ($users as $user)
    <a href="#" class="user"  style="color:#CB6F53"  wire:click.prevent="viewMessages({{ $user->id }} )">
      <div class="user-card rounded {{ $user->id === $selectedUser->id ? 'bg-dark' : '' }} bg-opacity-10 mb-1  rounded mb-1">
        <div class="mx-2">
          <div class="d-flex pt-3">
            @if($user->avator != Null)
              <img class="rounded-circle" width="48px" height="48px" src="{{Config('wfh.file').$user->avator}}" alt="">
            @else
              <img class="rounded-circle" width="48px" height="48px" src="{{url('')}}/uploads/images/php55DB.tmp.png" alt="">
            @endif

            <div class="notification-text ms-3 w-100">
              <span class="username fw-bold">{{$user->full_name}}</span>
              @if($user->messages->last()->created_at ?? null)
                @php
                  $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($user->messages->last()->created_at ?? Null));
                @endphp
                <span class="float-end small">{{ $newDate ?? Null}}</span>
              @endif
              @if($user->messages->last()->body ?? Null)
                <p class="mt-1 text-muted">You: {{$user->messages->last()->body ?? Null}} <span class="badge badge bg-danger">1</span></p>
              @else
                <p class="mt-1 text-muted"></p>
              @endif
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  @endforeach
@else
  <p class="text-center"><b>User not found !</b></p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two parts in your question:

1. Check if there are new messages: with livewire you can use "poll" directive:
   https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/polling#introduction

```html
<div wire:poll.keep-alive>
    Current time: {{ now() }}
</div>
```

This will refresh component if tab is active. You also can set interval for polling.

2. Hide element on click. For this I would recommend to use Alpine.js which has a very good connection with livewire.

```html
<div>
    <span @click="showNewMessageAlert = false">ClickMe</span>
 
    <div x-show="showNewMessageAlert = true">
        <!-- Here goes yor message alert -->
    </div>
</div>
```

You can find more examples here: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js